# rbenv and gems that require C extensions

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv, boxen

So I'm trying to install the [audite gem](https://github.com/georgi/audite), but having issues with rbenv:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Installing audite (0.3.0)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for mpg123.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby
please install mpg123 headers


Gem files will remain installed in /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/audite-0.3.0     for inspection.
Results logged to /opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/audite-0.3.0/ext/mpg123/gem_make.    out

An error occurred while installing audite (0.3.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install audite -v '0.3.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I know that these gems require c extensions, and I have them installed with homebrew. And if I go into the cellar for homebrew I can see the file it's looking for (`mpg123.h`)

```
/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/mpg123/1.15.4/include/mpg123.h
```

So, is there a way to add this into the rbenv environment without just sim-linking or copying it directly into `/opt/boxen/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p448/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end one of the following things fixed it for me, I'm not sure which because I'd rebuild and changed my machine few times since I had this issue:

- Switched to Ruby 2.0.0
- Upgraded to Mavericks (which does change some
  stuff with xcode stuff I believe)
- Updated my Boxen/Brew to latest
  version

Answer (score 2):

```
xcode-select --install
```

resolved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issues trying to install audite. Turns out that mkmf writes a file call mkmf.log to tell you more specifically what it does to find out if the headers are availbale or not:

```
 >>> cat mkmf.log
have_header: checking for mpg123.h... -------------------- no

"xcrun cc -E -I. -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/universal-darwin12.0 -I.  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE     -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -DENABLE_DTRACE  -fno-common  -pipe -fno-common    conftest.c -o conftest.i"
xcode-select: Error: No Xcode is selected. Use xcode-select -switch <path-to-xcode>, or see the xcode-select manpage (man xcode-select) for further information.
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include <mpg123.h>
/* end */

--------------------
```

Turns out that I hadn't had xcode installed yet; after installing it and running

```
xcode-select --print-path
```

I saw that the path was now set. Then I still had to run *xcrun* once to agree to Apple's licence agreements, but then the installed installed just fine!

Comment: No dice unfortunatly, but that log file is useful:
https://gist.github.com/petems/7791532

Comment: Curious! Maybe try creating a /usr/var/lib directory and softlink it to /var/lib ?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm having a similar issue as well.

Comment: @StefanNovak: Yes, as I explained in my post, installing xcode and xcrun did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add the homebrew `include` directory to your path, rubygems will find it. This isn't really a problem with rbenv.

In a default install, homebrew symlinks all the `include` folders of the packages to `/usr/local/include`, in your case, those should be in `/opt/boxen/homebrew/include`. Just have a look around, there should a be a folder somewhere containing all includes.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean add `/opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/mpg123/1.15.4/include/` to my path? Wouldn't I then have to do it for every C extension required, as I'm having a similar issue with portaudio too...

Comment: In the default homebrew install (to `/usr/local`) it creates an `/usr/local/include` folder. This should be present for you as well, in `/opt/boxen/homebrew/include`. This folder contains symlinks  pointing to the various `include` directories of the packages.

Comment: I gave it a a try, but no dice, theres my output as a gist: https://gist.github.com/petems/6812615

Comment: There might be a special devel header package for it.

Comment: I thought this would have been the solution but even adding INCLUDE=/usr/local/include explicitly at the front of my command-line it still pretends not to find it the header...